# calculating employee bonus through nested if statements

Tags: java

Hi I have a beginner java class and the assignment is to calculate productivity score and relate it to a dollar bonus amount variable.  It is mostly prewritten code from a cengage class without the if statements.  My grade check makes it through one employee, who gets a 50 dollar bonus but if I enter stats for someone who would get a higher bonus it still gives them the 50 dollar bonus.  I think I wrote the operands wrong or something but

```
// EmployeeBonus.java - This program calculates an employee's productivity bonus. 

   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class EmployeeBonus 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Declare and initialize variables here.
    String employeeName; 
    double numTransactions = 0; 
    String transactString;
    double numShifts = 0; 
    String shiftString;
    double dollarValue = 0;
    String dollarString;
    double score = 0;
    double bonus = dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;
    final double BONUS_1 = 50.00;
    final double BONUS_2 = 75.00;
    final double BONUS_3 = 100.00; 
    final double BONUS_4 = 200.00;
    
            
    // This is the work done in the housekeeping() method
    System.out.println("Enter employee's name: ");
    employeeName  = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter number of shifts: ");
    shiftString  = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter number of transactions: ");
    transactString  = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter transactions dollar value: ");
    dollarString  = s.nextLine();

    numShifts = Double.parseDouble(shiftString);
    numTransactions = Double.parseDouble(transactString);
    dollarValue = Double.parseDouble(dollarString);
    // This is the work done in the detailLoop() method
    // Write your code here
    if ( score <= 30)
    {
        bonus = BONUS_1;
    }
        if ( score >= 31 && score <= 69)
    {
        bonus = BONUS_2;
    }
        if ( score >= 70 && score <= 199)
    {
        bonus = BONUS_3;
    }
        if ( score >= 200)
    {
        bonus = BONUS_4;
    }
    // This is the work done in the endOfJob() method   
    // Output.  
    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employeeName);
    System.out.println("Employee Bonus: $" + bonus);

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: you are supposed to calculate `score` using  `dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;` this formula i guess.

Comment: Look at your code and look at every place where you change the value of `double score`. I only see you initializing score to 0, but never changing it. So when you do your if checks the first one will always be the only one entered.

Comment: omg i put the formula in the wrong place, edit nope that wasnt it actually that made it worse

Comment: So Im not initializing it past the first if statement, what would that look like? I tried  to put it in as a variable again and it said no

Comment: You don't need the ``System.exit(0);`` at the end.

Comment: most of it is prewritten. I just do the if statements @NomadMaker.  I don't even know what that is exactly.  They have pretty much only showed us how to initialize variables, basic math,  and how to do if and if-else statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you write the formula for `score` in `bonus` wrongly, so I have changed that.

Your code here

```
double numTransactions = 0;
String transactString;
double numShifts = 0;
String shiftString;
double dollarValue = 0;
String dollarString;
double score = dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;
double bonus = 0;
```

in this case, you are trying to calculate the value for `score` by dividing 0s (You have assigned 0 into dollarValue, numTransactions, numShifts). This will cause error occur. You should move `double score = dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;` this code after you have parse the value.

This is my attempt, correct me if I am wrong:

```
// EmployeeBonus.java - This program calculates an employee's productivity bonus.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeBonus {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Declare and initialize variables here.
    String employeeName;
    double numTransactions = 0;
    String transactString;
    double numShifts = 0;
    String shiftString;
    double dollarValue = 0;
    String dollarString;
    double bonus = 0;
    final double BONUS_1 = 50.00;
    final double BONUS_2 = 75.00;
    final double BONUS_3 = 100.00;
    final double BONUS_4 = 200.00;


    // This is the work done in the housekeeping() method
    System.out.println("Enter employee's name: ");
    employeeName  = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter number of shifts: ");
    shiftString  = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter number of transactions: ");
    transactString  = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter transactions dollar value: ");
    dollarString  = s.nextLine();

    numShifts = Double.parseDouble(shiftString);
    numTransactions = Double.parseDouble(transactString);
    dollarValue = Double.parseDouble(dollarString);

    // start calculate the score here
    double score = dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;

    // This is the work done in the detailLoop() method
    // Write your code here [I simplify your code here]
    if (score <= 30) {
        bonus = BONUS_1;
    } else if (score <= 69) {
        bonus = BONUS_2;
    } else if (score <= 199) {
        bonus = BONUS_3;
    } else {
        bonus = BONUS_4;
    }
    // This is the work done in the endOfJob() method
    // Output.
    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employeeName);
    System.out.println("Employee Bonus: $" + bonus);

    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: not allowed anything but IF statements.  But moving the code down after the parse did fix it.  If you aren't busy can you explain why this happens?

Comment: Like what I mentioned above, the moment you write the code `double score = dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;` , it is actually calculating and store it into the variable. Although you have assigned new values into `numShifts `, `numTransactions` and `dollarValue`, the value for `score` is still remain the same as you didn't use the newly assigned value to calculate it.

Comment: Besides, error will occur when you try to divide a number by 0. Unless you use `try...catch` to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing bonus and score from

```
double score = 0;
double bonus = dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;
```

to:

```
double bonus = 0;
double score = dollarValue / numTransactions / numShifts;
```

and then

```
if ( score <= 30)
    {
        bonus = BONUS_1;
    }
    else if ( score >= 31 && score <= 69)
    {
        bonus = BONUS_2;
    }
    else if ( score >= 70 && score <= 199)
    {
        bonus = BONUS_3;
    }
    else
    {
        bonus = BONUS_4;
    }
```

Comment: not allowed else statements, this lesson is just nested IF statements, this all could have been so simple I think